# lein ring server-headless - only listen to localhost?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

I have a Clojure project using lein-ring and the compojure web framework, which I start using the `lein ring server-headless` command. It produces the following output:

> 2014-06-28 19:37:50.236:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.8.v20121106
>   2014-06-28 19:37:50.315:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:3000
>   Started server on port 3000

I kind of just realized that this is listening on `0.0.0.0`. A `netstat -nltp` confirms this:

> tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      31781/java

Is it possible for `lein ring server-headless` to only listen to localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to configure Jetty to listen only on a specific interface, add the `:host` key into the `:ring {:handler ...}` map in your project.clj. The value should be the host name or the ip address of the interface on which Jetty should listen. For example, `:ring {:handler yourapp.handler/app :host "localhost"}` to listen on localhost only.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks!